# spring XD rabbit source module fails to process messages, first message stays unacknowledged

Tags: hadoop, spring-amqp, spring-xd

I am trying simple spring XD application to load log events in HDFS. I have configured the target application with the `spring-ampq/rabbit log4j appender` (the `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.log4j.AmqpAppender` Class) to pump log messages to a pre-configured exchange. I set the following stream to pull those messages from and push them to HDFS, where both soruce and sink modules are off-the-shelf XD modules,

stream definition,

```
xd:>stream create --name demoQ1 --definition "rabbit | hdfs --rollover=15 --directory=/user/root" --deploy
```

Created and deployed new stream 'demoQ1'

```
xd:>stream list
  Stream Name  Stream Definition                                   Status
  -----------  --------------------------------------------------  --------
  demoQ1       rabbit | hdfs --rollover=15 --directory=/user/root  deployed
```

AMQP Appender is publishing the messages to exchange and routing it to demoQ1 queue, where rabbit source is picking up the first message and then gets stuck, as it does not acknowledge the message. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

In your container log, do you see this: "failed to write Message payload to HDFS" ?

If so, then you need to use the type conversion between modules. From the rabbit source to hdfs sink the messages will simply be byte arrays.

Your stream definition could be,

stream create --name demoQ1 --definition "rabbit --outputType=text/plain | hdfs --rollover=15 --directory=/user/root" --deploy

or,

stream create --name demoQ1 --definition "rabbit | hdfs --inputType=text/plain --rollover=15 --directory=/user/root" --deploy

Note the outputType or the inputType option in source/sink respectively.
In this case, the hdfs sink's HdfsStoreMessageHandler expects the payload to be of type String.

For more details on the type conversion, please check this out: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki/Type-Conversion

Answer (score -1):

Enabled debug logs on the spring XD container running rabbit module, It showed following exception repeatedly happening for the first message and message is requeued back thus the message stays in unacknowledged state and rabbit source can not process further messages..

To resolve the problem, from log4j Appender properties I removed this property, `log4j.appender.amqp.contentEncoding=null`. This property explicitly specifies name of the encoder as "null", which seems to be a bug. I was expecting null means no encoder specified :)

Exception in the log, continuously repeating as message is rejected and re-queued back..

```
19:29:17,713 DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 listener.BlockingQueueConsumer:268 - Received message: (Body:'Hello'MessageProperties [headers={categoryName=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager, level=INFO}, timestamp=Sat Apr 19 19:21:52 PDT 2014, messageId=null, userId=null, appId=NodeManager, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=0, redelivered=true, receivedExchange=test-exch, receivedRoutingKey=rk1, deliveryTag=184015, messageCount=0]) 19:29:17,715 WARN SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer:530 - Execution of Rabbit message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set. org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:751) at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:690) at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:583) at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:75) at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:154) at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1111) at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:556) at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:904) at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:888) at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$500(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:75) at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:989) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to convert text-based Message content at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.fromMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:100) at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$1.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:73) at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:688) ... 10 more Caused by: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: null at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:190) at java.lang.String.(String.java:416) at java.lang.String.(String.java:481) at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.fromMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:97) ... 12 more 19:29:17,715 DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 listener.BlockingQueueConsumer:657 - Rejecting messages (requeue=true)
```